# Select tables that contains specific column name

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on PostreSQL and I have this code to select all the tables and their columns from my database

```sql
select t.table_name
     , array_agg(c.column_name::text) as columns
  from information_schema.tables t 
  join information_schema.columns c 
    on t.table_name = c.table_name
 where t.table_schema = 'public' 
   and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
   and c.table_schema = 'public'
 group 
    by t.table_name;
```

I'm trying to modify it to give me only the tables that contains specific column name e.g 'email'
The problem is that when I'm adding another "and" it only returns one column instead of all

```sql
 where t.table_schema = 'public' and t.table_type= 'BASE TABLE' and c.table_schema = 'public' and c.column_name = 'email'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a having clause:

```
select t.table_name
     , array_agg(c.column_name::text) as columns
  from information_schema.tables t 
  join information_schema.columns c 
    on t.table_name = c.table_name
   and t.table_schema = c.table_schema
 where t.table_schema = 'public' 
   and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
 group by t.table_name
 having 'email' = any(array_agg(c.column_name::text))
```

If you want to check for multiple columns you could do that like this:

```
select t.table_name
     , array_agg(c.column_name::text) as columns
  from information_schema.tables t 
  join information_schema.columns c 
    on t.table_name = c.table_name
   and t.table_schema = c.table_schema
 where t.table_schema = 'public' 
   and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
 group by t.table_name
 having array_agg(c.column_name::text) @> array['email', 'phone']
```